# android programming

Tags: android

I know what has to be done.. this is what i have to do..

create a custom listview (with checkboxes on the list row on the left) in your app, with the adapter getting data one be one to your app from contacts app using a service or thread, then inflate it on the view

But I am having trouble implementing it... 
i knw the basics too..then pass that arraylist in the adapter...

If any body can help me out.. I am stuck for past week on this...  I want to get it over with...

```
ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouWant> mArrayList = new ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouWant>();
for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); mCursor.moveToNext(); mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    // The Cursor is now set to the right position
    mArrayList.add(mCursor.getWhateverTypeYouWant(WHATEVER_COLUMN_INDEX_YOU_WANT));
}
```

Here is the code...

```
package com.exiom.productcatalogue;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebexAttendeeList extends Activity {

 ListView lstAttends;
 ListView lstContacts;
 private ArrayList<String> aAttendees = new ArrayList<String>();
 private ArrayList<String> aContacts= new ArrayList<String>();

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webexattendees);

//      lstContacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstContacts);
        lstAttends = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstAttendees);

        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> sContact = new HashMap<String, String>();

     if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
      while (cur.moveToNext()) {
          String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
          String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
          sContact = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query( 
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
      null,
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
      new String[]{id}, null); 
     while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
         // This would allow you get several email addresses
            // if the email addresses were stored in an array
         String email = emailCur.getString(
                          emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
//          String emailType = emailCur.getString(
//                          emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
         sContact.put("name", name);
         sContact.put("email", email);
         mylist.add(sContact);
        aAttendees.add(name);
      } 
      emailCur.close();

      }
      cur.close();
   }

 //   SimpleAdapter mAttendees = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.multicolumnlayout,
//            new String[] {"name", "email"}, new int[] {R.id.NAME, R.id.EMAIL});
//        lstContacts.setAdapter(mAttendees);
//     lstContacts.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
     ArrayAdapter<String> attendAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, aAttendees);
     lstAttends.setAdapter(attendAdapter);
        lstAttends.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

     Button btnStart = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnStartWebex);
     btnStart.setOnClickListener(mStartButtonListener);
     Button btnCancel = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnWebexCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(mCancelButtonListener);
//        lstContacts.setOnClickListener(mSelectAttendee);

    }

    public void StartWebEx()
    {
//     WebexClient webex = null ;
//     String webExId = "";
//  String backUrl = "";
//  
//  webex.getLoginUrl(webExId, backUrl);

     int len = lstAttends.getCount();
     SparseBooleanArray checked = lstAttends.getCheckedItemPositions();
     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
      if (checked.get(i)) {
       String item = aAttendees.get(i).toString();
       /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
      }
    }

    private OnClickListener mStartButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Starting WebEx...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//      String sSQLCmd = "update U_WEBEX_SETTING set webex_url = '"+edtWURL.getText()+"', "
//               + "webex_id = '"+edtWID.getText()+"', "
//               + "webex_pw = '"+edtWPW.getText()+"'";
//      
//      db.execSQL(sSQLCmd);
      StartWebEx();
      finish();
     };
    };

    private OnClickListener mCancelButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
     // do something when the button is clicked
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exiting WebEx...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     finish();
     };
    };

    private OnClickListener mSelectAttendee = new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
       // do something when the button is clicked
                    //     aAttendees.add(lstContacts);
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       finish();
       };
      };

}
```

Comment: wt u edit.. u didnt do anything :S

Comment: Where did you stuck? How can we help you?

Comment: i m stuck  at  creating  a custom listview (with checkboxes on the list row on the left) in your app, with the adapter getting data one be one to your app from contacts app using a service or thread, then inflate it on the view  basically when the attendee button is clicked i should a list of contacts with checkboxes and with two buttons start and cancel.. i have buttons functioning.. i just need to implement the contacts

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will be helpful to you.
[Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: i m not getting how to implement it in this

Comment: create a custom listview (with checkboxes on the list row on the left) in your app, with the adapter getting data one be one to your app from contacts app using a service or thread, then inflate it on the view

Comment: You told you've done the layout part of the work, than all that remains is just injecting the contacts into your app. The post at developer.android.com is describing this problem very clearly, you should read this carefully and try to understand, try it in practice. There's not much I can help you in written form. Hope you resolve your problem.

Comment: i m still now able to do it... can u just give me a sample solution similar to this :(

Comment: nvm i got it wrking..
but now what i need to do is... when i click start it gets the selected ones and it goes to the xml and stores the information there...  can u guide me????